# Why doesn't 1-way binding work in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having trouble using one way binding in directives with an isolate scope.

If I use an equal sign for two-way binding, and use the data like so: `{{d.name}}`, it works.

If I use an @ sign, it doesn't work. If I use an equal sign and use the data like so: `{{::d.name}}`, it fails also.

You can see my full example at this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8bUl8pZSV8Ryru6GDq2M?p=preview

Can someone please help me understand what's happening here? Thanks.

Comment: The @ gives you one-way binding of a scope variable to the text of the attribute. The :: gives you one-*time* binding, which is something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one-way binding syntax you are trying to use, has been introduced since Angular 1.3.
In your demo you are using version 1.2.25.
You must change the script link:

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.25"></script>
```

The problem with the second directive, instead, is that the `@` is not a one-way binding, it simply takes the attribute as text.
To use it like you would, so you need to interpolate the text before passing it to the directive, like this

```
<h3>Directive 2</h3>
<p ng-repeat="d in data">
  <dir2 d="{{d.name}}"></dir2>
</p>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5FqG6kNUDekJX9Hg4pI?p=preview)

Comment: You nailed it, thanks! Updating my Angular fixed the issue with the `{{::d.name}}` syntax. And the @ only passing a string makes sense, didn't know that's how it worked.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at this link https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/. It explains well how to use ```@```,```=``` and ```&```.